# Inbox items are falling down one line sometimes

Tags: bug, global-inbox, top-bar

Take a look on this inbox: (old style)

> [image]

Now here is what I see in the new design:

> [image]

See the problem? One line is just wasted. It happened before but yesterday was fine so I thought "cool, they fixed it" just to see it happening again today. Still trying to figure what can cause this.

Chrome 31.0.1650.57 m, Windows 7 here.

Comment: I don't have that problem http://i.stack.imgur.com/Cmjdw.jpg  Using latest chrome(Version 31.0.1650.57 m) with Win8.

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan cheers, so it's not a global problem. Keep an eye though, wonder if it will fall for you too.

Comment: Using Firefox 25.0.1 on Windows 7 I'm not able to reproduce this either, nor on Chrome 31.0.1650.57m on the same Windows 7 machine.

Comment: @psubsee2003 so it's likely some kind of items causing this. <scratches head helplessly>

Comment: No repro [IE 10 on Win RT].

Comment: Are you still seeing this happen after we changed the inbox format?

Comment: @Nick think I saw it few days ago but now it looks fine - will also see from the office computer tomorrow to confirm. Thanks!